# Service to monitor Service not triggering

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, systemd, service

On Ubuntu 18 I have a service :

```
[Unit]
Description=Gets CSV
OnFailure=pushovercsv.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vehicles.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This works. I am trying unsuccessfully to setup another service which alerts me if the first service is stopped or in failed sate:

**pushovercsv.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=PushOver Notifaction for vehicles CSV Service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=curl -s --form-string "token=<secret>" --form-string "user=<secret>" --form-string "message=CSV service"   https://<pushover api endpoint>

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Both services work on there own.

But it doesn't appear as if `OnFailure=pushovercsv.service` is calling the pushover service. If I stop the first service with `systemctl stop service1` I get no alert from pushovercsv.service.

Does pushovercsv.service need to be manually started or is it started when called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As its name suggests, `OnFailure=` is only triggered when the unit fails (exits with a non-zero exit code, killed by a signal, or similar). If you want to run a command whenever the service stops, you don't even need a separate service, just [`ExecStopPost=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStopPost=) is enough.

Comment: So if I include OnFailure and ExecStopPost it will trigger on Failure or Stop?

Comment: @AlGrant They'll act separately. If the service fails, both `OnFailure` unit and `ExecStopPost` command will be started/executed.